# How can i run popup window without error on casperjs?

Tags: casperjs, popupwindow

I set wait below code.

```
casper.options.waitTimeout = 50000;
```

I get timeout error.
so I cannot run popup screen on casperjs.
I have tried codes below. How to make this work and how to use `casper.withPopup` properly with the popup?

```
casper.then(function() {
casper.page.injectJs('jquery.js'); 
this.clickLabel('Follow', 'div');
this.wait(5000);
/* this.waitForPopup(/www.domain.com/, function(){
this.test.pass("popup opened");
}); /
});
/ casper.then(function() {
this.wait(5000);
this.capture("screen.png"); 
});
*/
```

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: i did thanks. but no errors or message